# How do I create a Hilbert curve that is bounded by a polygon?

Tags: fractals, polygons

All images of the Hilbert curve that I've seen show the Hilbert curve as bounded by the unit square:

[image: Hilbert curve]

However, if I have a list of vertices that define a closed polygon, how can I create a Hilbert curve that is **bounded by the edges of this polygon, instead of a square?** Is this even possible?

Comment: If you feel adventurous, try a Schwarz–Christoffel mapping.

Answer (score 1):

If the polygon is star-shaped is easy to find a homeomorphism between it and the square. Compose the curve with this homeomorphism.

Comment: You do not need star shaped, just a regions bounded by a simple polygonal loop.

Comment: I understand a *reasonably* explicit formula.